# Why ordinary oil was not recommended in Millikan oil drop experiment?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

Why was it recommended not to use ordinary oil in Millikan oil drop experiment? What were the properties of oil used by Millikan?

Comment: Ordinary oil may contain double bonds that may chemically react in the experiment.

Comment: What is "ordinary oil"? There is a huge variety of chemicals called "oils" with a very wide range of properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Converting my comment into answer:</sub>

Quoting [from here:](https://byjus.com/chemistry/oil-drop-experiment/)

> Ordinary oil wasn’t used for the experiment as it would evaporate by the heat of the light and so could cause an error in the Millikens Oil Drop Experiment. So, the oil that is generally used in a vacuum apparatus which is of low vapour pressure was used.

What type of oil is used then? Please check: [Which oil was used by Robert A. Millikan in his oil drop experiment?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/292143/which-oil-was-used-by-robert-a-millikan-in-his-oil-drop-experiment)